# Move my question to english.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, asking-questions

Two weeks ago I asked a question whether to use the hyphen or the en dash in cases like Anglo-Saxon England and The Washington–Moscow hotline on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/.

[Whether to choose the hyphen or the en dash in cases like "Anglo-Saxon England" or "The Washington-Moscow hotline"?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/143547/whether-to-choose-the-hyphen-or-the-en-dash-in-cases-like-anglo-saxon-england)

I had wrongly supposed that this question is related to typography but thanks to Billy Kerr who answered it, it is now obvious that it is actually about English.

May I ask to move it to https://english.stackexchange.com/? I think it would a better place for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct  in that the question is more about the use of English language in general and less about typography. It would be a better fit on English.SE.

However, we typically do not migrate questions once they have received answers. This is for a variety of reasons. The main reason here would be because it would cause Billy to lose their rep for the upvotes on their answer.

From this [Meta.SE Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work):

> **Avoid migrating answered questions**. The point of migration is to send
> the question to a place where it is on-topic and can get answered. If
> the OP already has an answer, then we've already defeated the purpose
> of migration and the destination site won't have anything to do with
> the question. Avoid migrating these questions unless they are of
> extremely good quality and risk deletion on their current site.